# Post Glimpse / Mini-Profiler log information to web api or webservice

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, mvc-mini-profiler, glimpse

Is there any possibility to post Glimpse or Mini-Profiler log information to a web api / webservice in order to separate the logged data storing (saving to a database) part from the main application.

We would be able to capture Mini-Profiler logged data within the Application_EndRequest() but we can not use any asynchronous calls to post data into web api inside this method. Any help or advice would be really appreciated.

Thanks
DSR

Answer (score 1):

Glimpse has an interface called `IPersistenceStore` that is used persist "logged data".

You could implement that interface and persist the data in any way you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will give it try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with MiniProfiler by creating your own implementation of [`IStorage`](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage/IStorage.cs) that will define your logic for storing and retrieving profiles into/from your api/webservice and set [`MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage`](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/MiniProfiler.Settings.cs#L306) to your implementation. You can also use [`MultiStorageProvider`](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage/MultiStorageProvider.cs) to define more than one storage location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will give it try and let you know.